# Selecting/grouping top/bottom *x* rows in a pivot table based on a sort of values

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, pivot-table

I am trying to group items in a pivot table based on a sorting of the values for those rows. I'm trying to set up a pareto chart based on this data. I've looked through a number of questions here on SO and on google, but was not able to find much help... It looks like this is not really that common a problem, unfortunately.

**Example**:

*Original Pivot*

```
State  |  Count
AK     |  14
AL     |  76
AR     |  40
AZ     |  129
CA     |  2666
CO     |  244
CT     |  61
```

*Sorted Pivot*

```
State  |  Count
CA     |  2666
CO     |  244
AZ     |  129
AL     |  76
CT     |  61
AR     |  40
AK     |  14
```

*Grouped/Final Pivot*

```
State  |  Count
CA     |  2666
CO     |  244
AZ     |  129
OTHER  |  191
```

I've never done pivot sorting/grouping in VBA before (but manually doing this is fairly simple), so I started with recording a macro. I figured out how to apply the sort in the first place, but trying to group gave me something like this:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PT7").PivotSelect _
    "State[AL,CT,AR,AK] Original 'NON-AA'", _
    xlDataAndLabel + xlFirstRow, True
```

The problem with this is that the states are hard-coded based on the values in the pivots. If I wanted to run this grouping on another set of data where a different state is below the threshold (top 3 rows, not actual value of `count`), then the wrong states would be included.

Is there a way to read just the top/bottom *x* number of rows without needing to know which row labels those correspond to?

I want something to work like this (using row numbers instead of captions/labels):

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PT7").PivotSelect _
    "State[4, 5, 6, 7] Original 'NON-AA'", _
    xlDataAndLabel + xlFirstRow, True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have solved this on my own -- needs to be refactored.

```
Dim iFilterLoop As Integer
Dim vValue2List As Variant
Dim sValue2List As String


vValue2List = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PT7").RowRange.Value2
sValue2List = ""

'Here's the key step in reading the string values:
For iFilterLoop = 4 To ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PT7").RowRange.Count ' Get all but the top 3 -- skip the first (start at 4), since that's the title
    sValue2List = sValue2List & vValue2List(iFilterLoop, 1) & ","
Next iFilterLoop

sValue2List = Left(sValue2List, Len(sValue2List) - 1)

ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PT7").PivotSelect( _
"State[" & sValue2List & "] Original 'NON-AA'", _
xlDataAndLabel + xlFirstRow, True).Group
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this does it:

```
Sub GroupLowerPivotItems()
Dim pt As Excel.PivotTable
Dim ptField As Excel.PivotField
Dim ptItem As Excel.PivotItem
Dim GroupStart As Long
Dim FirstCell As Excel.Range
Dim LastCell As Excel.Range

GroupStart = 4
Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
Set ptField = pt.PivotFields("State")
Set ptItem = ptField.PivotItems(GroupStart)
Set FirstCell = ptItem.LabelRange
Set ptItem = ptField.PivotItems(ptField.PivotItems.Count)
Set LastCell = ptItem.LabelRange
pt.Parent.Range(FirstCell, LastCell).Group
End Sub
```

Comment: This appears to be a better solution than what I came up with, but both seem to work well.

Comment: I take that back... It looks like the `PivotItems(value)` pulls the unsorted order, meaning no matter what sorting I do for the data fields, the row fields keep their index.

Comment: I'm not quite sure of whether this is working for you or not. When I wrote it I did a quick test with data sorted in two directions and it seemed to work in both cases. If not, I'd be doing something similar to your answer with the label range for the field. BTW, I upvoted this question. It's an interesting one.

Comment: Thank you. :-) I did not do any extensive testing, so honestly, it may be something I'm doing on my part. I'm now dug into this, moving on to my next steps in coding, but once I've got more time to come back, I'll try and verify better.